# When submitting resume and cover letter, is it okay to add additional documents which may be relevant?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, applications

I'm applying for a job and on the posting it mentions that cover letter and resume are required and to send cover letter and resume to a specific email.

It's for a programming tutoring position. I previously worked as a programming tutor and developed basic instructional material. I put down on my resume that I did this. I was wondering if it is okay (recommended, or not recommended) to attach a .PDF file (of the instructional material) in the email? I was thinking of writing this in the body of the email: "For your reference, I have attached instructional material which I created while previously tutoring students (which I have talked about on my resume)".

Okay, good idea or bad idea?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was a private tutor for two high school students. I used a well known textbook as a reference and created a much shorter version as a guide which I used when teaching (basically my rough notes when I read the book.. 5 pages instead of 50). I created my own exercises similar to that used in the textbook. In my guide, I mentioned that the textbook was used as a reference. I didn't use the textbook itself because it was very long and the students were way too lazy and intimidated to even look at it. My notes were a lot more "lazy student friendly".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I own the instructional material I created while I was a private tutor, yes. This is what I plan to show. I do not own the textbook which I took notes from (the notes I took are basically the instructional material).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> good idea or bad idea?

Personally, I wouldn't attach these to a resume.

Many companies have automated systems in which your information is filed. These additional documents may not fit their system well. Since your resume and cover letter will likely be passed around within the hiring company, they don't want to include other documents that may get lost or shuffled around. Just go with the resume and cover letter initially.

Additionally, the initial screeners of your resume and cover letter spend very little time on your documents. You probably want them to focus on your overall fit for the position rather than spending their scarce time looking at your tutorial and trying to decide if it makes sense for their position or not.

Do bring copies of this tutorial (and any other materials you have developed that aren't owned by another company) as part of your "portfolio". When the topic of developing tutorials comes up, offer to show them the one you have developed. Then the interviewer can ask you questions about how you developed them, the thought behind them, and how you might do the same for the job at hand - all while looking at your real-world example.

Answer (score 5):

While applying for a job, you should only send the documents that are required for the job.

You should not attach any other documents (.PDF file of the instructional material) in the email. If it is something which is related to the job you are applying for and you think you should showcase it then, you just need to mention in your resume (which you already did).
During personal interview, you can discuss more about this.

Comment: "Portfolio/samples available on request." Or perhaps "available at mysite.com/samples".

Comment: Or add the URL linking to your LinkedIn profile and put up samples of your work there.